# ArrayList<String> in toString method of Class

Tags: java

I have an `ArrayList<String>` as a field of a class, I want to print the `ArrayList` in the method `toString` of this Class. How am I suppose to do that?

Comment: Override the `toString` method http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=55

Comment: `toString` doesn't print anything, unless you're doing it very wrong.

Comment: Call the `toString` of your list and treat it like as normal.

Comment: Like How? Can  you give me an example please

Answer (score 1):

As it is an `ArrayList`, you can use it's [`toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString--) if your satiesfied with its behaviour.

> Returns a string representation of this collection. The string representation consists of a list of the collection's elements in the order they are returned by its iterator, enclosed in square brackets (`"[]"`). Adjacent elements are separated by the characters `", "` (comma and space). Elements are converted to strings as by [`String.valueOf(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf-java.lang.Object-).

E.g.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "There are " + list.toString() + " in my pocket";
}
```

Note: in the above example `toString` is not need to be called explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Coming from the C# background, this may not be the correct sythax, but it should illustrate the general idea:

```
public class PrintableAray<T> : ArrayList<T>
{
    @Override public String toString()
    {
       string s = "[";
       //join all the raw values into together by e.g. comma
       s += "]";
       return s;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does that means C#'s array list does not have a decent toString?

Comment: well not with ToString() directly. You can however write `string.Join(", ", myArray.Select(v => v.ToString()))`

Comment: *<part of it deleted>* BTW, I think composition is better in this case (in Java) if you want to make a new type for this.

Comment: well how many times do you really need a whole array as a string. And if you need it, you can still have it in your own class.

Comment: Well I don't really represent the community, it's my humble opinion that is subject to change.